# Swift VAR assignment

Tags: swift

I want to know if I can assign a value to a VAR later in code like this

```
var myView: UIView

func createView() {

  myView = UIView() {

 let _view = UIView()
  ... do more stuff ...
 return _view
 }()

}
```

is that a common way to deal with var?

Comment: I am a little confused by the question, but you should be able to assign anything of the same type to a `var` later on, `let` is the 1 assignment variable tho. `var` can also be nil or an empty optional.

Comment: I got it to work only if when I declare it like this: var myView: UIView = UIView() otherwise it throws an error

Comment: You can do `var myView: UIView?` and then you will need to do optional checks later on but it allows for myView to be nil at init time.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to return a view lazily then the way to do it is with a lazy property.

```
lazy var myView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    // configure the view
    return view
}()
```

This creates your myView when it is asked for. The closure is only run once, so after you create it, asking for the `myView` property will return the view that you've already created, not a new one.

Comment: I only want to declare the variable at the top of the file and then in assign it later in some function.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Initialization section](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) of the Swift Programming Language Guide:

> Classes and structures must set all of their stored properties to an
>   appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or
>   structure is created. Stored properties cannot be left in an
>   indeterminate state.

This means you either have to immediately provide a default value when you declare the variable or assign a value in an initializer.

If your variable is an `Optional` you won't need to specify a value before using the variable:

```
var myView: UIView?
```

In that case `myView` defaults to `nil` (meaning it has no value).

Another option would be to use lazy initialization as already pointed out in Abizern's answer.

If you can't initialize the variable when you declare it or inside of an initializer, but you know for sure that it will have a value before you use it for the first time, you can declare it as an Implicitly Unwrapped Optional and have it be automatically unwrapped when you use it:

```
var myView: UIView!
```

This can, however, lead to crashes if you accidentally try to access the (non existing) value of the variable before initializing it - IUOs are Optionals after all, so `myView` will still default to `nil`.